# java.io.FileNotFoundException error when loading an remote URL

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to read a cdv file into my java program written in eclipse on mac. This works fine when I read the file from a directory on my computer but I would like to read a csv file from the web (Yahoo Finance in my case). This works perfectly fine on a PC so it is probably Mac related. I have tested a few different options, using backslash, multiple backslashes etc. but I cannot get it working so I turn to you smart people out here.

This is my code:

```
public void run() {

          String csvFile = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPHS&a=05&b=9&c=2013&d=09&e=12&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv";
          System.out.println(csvFile);
          BufferedReader br = null;
          String line = "";
          String csvSplitBy = ",";

          try {

              br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                  String[] output = line.split(csvSplitBy);

                  System.out.println("On "+output[0]+" Closing price was: "+output[6]);
              }
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              if (br != null) {
                  try {
                      br.close();
                  }catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }

          System.out.println("Done!");

      }
```

This is the error and output I get:

```
http:\\ichart.finance.yahoo.com\table.csv?s=SPHS&a=05&b=9&c=2013&d=09&e=12&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\\ichart.finance.yahoo.com\table.csv?s=SPHS&a=05&b=9&c=2013&d=09&e=12&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at ReadCSV.ReadCSV.run(ReadCSV.java:28)
    at ReadCSV.ReadCSV.main(ReadCSV.java:13)
Done!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `FileReader` to get contents from a remote URL.

You can use `URL` class:

```
URL url = new URL("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPHS&a=05&b=9&c=2013&d=09&e=12&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
// Read URL's  content from `is`
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```

The problem has nothing to do with Mac os Eclipse. You'll get the same error on every platform.

Comment: Are you sure it's UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

```
new FileReader(csvFile)
```

That's not a local file. Create a `URL` object:

```
URL url=new URL("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPHS&a=05&b=9&c=2013&d=09&e=12&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv");
```

and load it with:

```
br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```